# How do I get a planar fluid surface in Flip Fluids?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I saw a video of someone making a U-boat surfacing with Flip Fluids, and I noticed the fluid surface is planar and it doesn’t just fall down onto the domains bottom side, and it has proper splashes. With mine it just falls to the domain and when I pass an object through it it just pushes the fluid out of the way instead of splashes. How do I make this effect?

Unfortunately I can’t share a screenshot since the screenshot is more than 2 mb.

https://youtu.be/-N-jqTs059o?si=UVCicY6a9EjeeABh

Comment: "Unfortunately I can’t share a screenshot since the screenshot is more than 2 mb". -> uhm...sorry, but you can scale down every screenshot. Also you could link to the video so we know what you are talking about.

Comment: @Chris I can gladly send the video link but when I tried to scale down the photo the smallest scale was 2.4 mb

Comment: how did u try to scale down your photo? just google "windows scale down photo"  and you should find a lot of ways to do it and for sure it can be scaled down to a smaller size

Comment: @Chris Oh, alright then. What I did was select my photo and I got the option to use ‘full size’, ‘med size’, ‘low’ etc.

Comment: please provide your blend file if my answer doesn't help you so that we can check out your settings, thx. To provide blend file, open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions.thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by enabling the **Domain > Surface > Remove Mesh Near Boundary** option.

From [Meshing Against Boundary Documentation](https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/wiki/Domain-Surface-Settings#meshing-against-boundary):

> **Remove Mesh Near Boundary**
> Remove parts of the surface mesh that are near the domain boundary. If a meshing volume object is set, parts of the mesh that are near the volume object boundary will also be removed.

[image]

Something to note is that this option will not speed up the simulation. This is only a post-processing effect that removes polygons from the surface mesh.

Answer (score 1):

ok, the "trick" that the surface stays flat, is that you just copy your domain object and make it a very little bit smaller and then just move the top face down. And of course after copying the domain you have to change it from domain to fluid. By this the fluid "stays" planar.

like this:

[image]

hope that helps.

you will get this:

[image]

by just doing this:

- add a mesh object -> obstacle
- animate that object
- use standard flip fluid settings, except:

  - resolution 120 (the more your computer can take, the better)
  - enable whitewater simulation
- choose the flip fluid materials:

[image]

Comment: I usually do this, but I wanted to know how to make it planar since it would probably save time computing it. Thanks anyways though!